# What happens when a webpage is closed?

Tags: javascript, ajax, html

**1) What happens in the background when a webpage is closed?**

**2) How can I make the webserver think the page is still being viewed so my script may run?**

I would post some code but I don't know where to start, looking for some terms and suggested methods to pursue, not necessarily code examples.

**Example:**

Let's say I have a javascript that needs to run for a certain amount of time once the user visits the page, but the user closes the page before it completes.

How **can I (fake) the connection as being alive** (even though **the user left**) until the script completes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## What happens in the background when a webpage is closed?

`unload` event is triggered and handled, script execution gets stopped, all webworkers get killed, everything gets cleaned up from memory, etc.

## How can I make the webserver think the page is still being viewed so my script may run?

What however *is* possible to start an ajax request in your page which doesn't get killed by the server when the client aborts the request. In php for example you should take a look for that at [`ignore_user_abort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php).

Comment: if I echo javascript in php, then ignore_user_abort() will that work?

Comment: No, the only reason php continues to execute is because it is running on your servers. The client is out of the equation by this point

Comment: ignore_user_abort() will only prevent stopping the PHP script. You can't prevent the JS from being aborted, as it needs the "sandbox" (window/tab) to be executed, and you can't stop the window/tab from being closed. All you can do is to tell the user that something needs to be done before he leaves and ask him not to close the window for some time - see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to warn user before leaving the page, and tell him that some work still needs to be done - but nothing more than that, the user will still be able to close the window/tab and your script will abort.

To warn the user, try this:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return 'Just give me a minute, please';
};
```